# How to pass the casesensitive object.property to Javascript from vba?

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-word, acrobat

Using Acrobat.tlb reference I create a Form field from Word via vba.

```
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set objPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
objPDDoc.Open (sFilep)
Set jso = objPDDoc.GetJSObject
Set mForma = jso.addField("Chb1", "checkbox", 0, Array(260, 700, 270, 690))
```

Now I would like to set some custom properties for this checkbox.

```
mForma.TextColor = Array("RGB", 0, 0, 245)
```

Everything is fine until I try to set the style property of checkbox because vba always change the **style** to **Style** (with capital S).
So how to force vba to process

```
mForma.style = "style.cr"
```

instead of

```
mForma.Style = "style.cr"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've got your answer here: [Acrobat Forms API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/FormsAPIReference.pdf#page=149)
This is for VB, but hopefully will also work in VBA. Give it a shot!

You should be able to assign like this:

`mForma.style = "check"`